# e.message() and mergeMethod in a mergeSort Java

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, merge

This is for my Data Structures class:  I have to do a merge sort.  I can only change the merge Method.

```
// merge sort
public void mergeSort(Card[] cardArray)
{
    mergeSortRec(cardArray, 0, cardArray.length - 1);
} 

// recursive helper recursive method for mergeSort
public void mergeSortRec(Card[] cardArray, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    if (startIndex < endIndex)
    {
        int midIndex = (startIndex + endIndex) / 2;
        mergeSortRec(cardArray, startIndex, midIndex);
        mergeSortRec(cardArray, midIndex + 1, endIndex);
        merge(cardArray, startIndex, endIndex);
    }
}
```

This is the method I am working on and I keep getting a e.message() 28.  I assume that means a null pointer problem.  i just don't see it. The compares() compares the two card and that method does work.  I also cant change parameters.

```
// merge two sorted halves into one sorted array
public void merge(Card[] cardArray, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    int index = startIndex;
    Card[] temp = new Card[cardArray.length];
    while (startIndex <= endIndex) {
        if (compares(cardArray[startIndex], cardArray[endIndex]) == -1) {
            temp[index] = cardArray[startIndex];

            startIndex++;
        } else {
            temp[index] = cardArray[endIndex];

            endIndex++;
        }
        index++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= cardArray.length; i++) {

        temp[i] = cardArray[i];
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `e.message()` it's not present in your code.

Comment: Its part of my test code                                                                                                             catch (Exception e)
        {
          System.out.println("Error occurred: " + e.getMessage());   
        }

Answer (score 0):

The parameters to merge are unusual. You'll need to calculate middle+1 again, and use that to start the compare loop (the first compare is [startIndex], [middle+1]). You'll need to check to see if the end of a half array has been reached, in which case you copy the remainder of the other half array. The last line should be cardArray[i] = temp[i] .